# Handle single quotes & special characters for SQL query

Tags: php

How would I handle single quotes (`'`) and special characters (`ûü`) in SQL queries? 
Such that if I enter `fdgbfd'ûü` my database will show exactly `fdgbfd'ûü` as its entry.

Comment: Can you give us some more info / background?

Comment: what happening is that if I've a string="abc's" sql query is not executed. I dont want to add addslashes()

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input']) . "')";
```

If you're referring to a different RDBMS, use the string escaping function provided by that database's PHP driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'fdgbfd\'ûü';
```

or

```
$string = "fdgbfd'ûü";
```

You should make sure you use UTF-8 / Unicode encoding for both the PHP files (if you assign a utf-8 value to a variable like above) and the database.

You should always use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or even better use PDO's prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php